# How to use .less file in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, less

I created a `.less` file in my `assets/css/myfile.less` Nuxt folder and I added some CSS to it.

```css
.edit-btn-color {
  background-color: #b1c646;
  color: white;
}
.edit-btn-color:hover {
  background-color: darken(#b1c646, 10%);
  color: white;
}
```

and in `nuxt.config.js` I do the following:

```js
export default {
  less: ['@/assets/css/myfile.less'],
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Nuxt2 is still using Webpack4, you need to install the v7 of `less-loader` ([v8 is using Webpack5](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0))

```
yarn add less-loader@^7 less
```

Then, create a `.less` file somewhere, like `/assets/css/myfile.less`

And use it in `nuxt.config.js` with this

```js
export default {
  css: ['~/assets/css/myfile.less'],
}
```

The key to use here is `css`, it's the same for SCSS, SASS, Less, Stylus and so on, as shown in the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#the-css-property

Answer (score 1):

The answer for **Nuxt v3** would be:

1. Install Less: `npm i less` (no `less-loader` needed).
2. For Global styles add them to your `nuxt.config.ts` like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['~/assets/less/main.less'],
})
```

3. In your components you could use Less like this:

```html
<style lang="less" scoped>
@import (reference) '../assets/less/helpers.less';
nav {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  .my-great-style; /* Imported from helpers.less */
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you land here and wonder how `(reference)`works, and what other options are: https://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature-import-options